# Caesar's Cipher - C

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I was working on a problem set for Caesar's cipher in C. I think I got the program to work. Ideally, we want to account for larger keys that are greater than 26 (hence using %).

My code: https://github.com/al2613/caesar-cipher-c/blob/master/caesar.c

I was taking a look at potential solutions as well and found the following:
https://gist.github.com/CraigRodrigues/100ab759b6b6722ba3ad8acf12e26371

Both seem to have the same output (i.e. key = 53 for hello becomes ifmmp)

I'm curious as to why both work? Is it necessary to include this section:

```
 if (islower(plain_text[i]))
   {
       if (encrypt > 122)
       {
           printf("%c", 96 + ((encrypt - 122) % 26));
       }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", encrypt);
        }
```

It appears Craig's solution is cleaner. I've seen people use x - 122 or x - 90 method to account for ASCII values that go beyond aA-zZ which was why I incorporated it. But I'm not entirely sure how or why this works especially in the context of mod 26.

Comment: Post relevant code here.  [MCVE]

Comment: When you talk about the "key" of a Caesar cipher I assume you mean the shift or modulus, but that's pretty much by definition limited to at most 26  (And the security of rot26 is especially poor).  You mentioned rot53, but that's equivalent to `53 % `` which is rot 1.  Rot1 of "hello" is "ifmmp"; I don't know where you got "hfnlp".

Comment: `96` is the *backtick* which is the character before the *lower-case* characters `[a-z]`. Taking `% 26` of any number will return `0-25`. So `96 + (0-25)` will results in a character `backtic - y` (which seems off-by-one if the goal is a lower-case `[a-z]`.

Comment: For capital letters the basic recipe is `(c - 'A' + k) % 26 + 'A', and for lower-case letters it's the same, but based on `'a'` rather than `'A'`.  Caesar ciphers always map letters to letters, and don't touch punctuation.